# Runaway argument? { \end {thebibliography} ! File ended while scanning use of \BRorg@thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, miktex

I'm entirely new to LaTex. Have very little idea about things. So our university gave us a sample of report and I'm modifying the content. Whenever I try to do bibliography & citation, it gives me very strange following error:

> Runaway argument?
>
> { \end {thebibliography}
>
> ! File ended while scanning use of \BRorg@thebibliography.
>
> \par
>
> l.230     \bibliography{reference}

Whenver I comment our these lines, it works perfectly fine:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference2}
```

I've following bib file (with sample references):

[image: BibFile]

I'm very tired of searching. Please help and have a look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm not sure whether it might be responsible for the reported error, but the entry in the bib file for Pan doesn't have an entry type identified. It looks like it is an article.

Comment: Hi @barbarabeeton! I tried to empty the bib file. But nothing seems to work

Comment: Don't show a screenshot, show a small but complete example of your tex file and copy the bib-entries (if they are relevant).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "empty the bib file".  barbarabeeton is saying that instead of `{Pan,`, you need something like `@ARTICLE{Pan,`.

Comment: You should also delete the old `.bbl` file -- that's what LaTeX reads that contains the error.  It has to be rebuilt after you fix the `.bib` file.

Comment: I emptied the file means that I removed all contents from file. But that won't work either

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are true life saver dear. Can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this problem.  Both must be attended to simultaneously.  Fixing either one separately won't solve the problem.

First, the compile is reading the `.bbl` file, so that will need to be removed and rebuilt.  But before removing it, it's worth looking at it to see if you can spot a place where the code looks flaky.  (The `.bbl` file wasn't shown in the question, so can't be specific.)

Next, look at the `.bib` file.  The obvious things to look for are incomplete entries -- missing closing braces or commas are the usual culprits, but that's not the case here.  However, there's something else that appears to be incomplete:
After the entry beginning `@BOOK{MG,` there is an incomplete entry beginning `{Pan,` with no entry type.  I can't say for sure that this is what has caused the problem, but it does need to be fixed.  It looks like an entry from a journal, so change it to

```
@ARTICLE{Pan,
```

Then, after making sure the old `.bbl` file has been removed, reprocess, recreating the `.bbl` file from the updated `.bib` file.  Check to make sure there were no errors in the Bibtex run; that will create a `.blg` file as a record, and it's worthwhile to become familiar with that, since errors in the Bibtex run will usually have repercussions in the LaTeX run, even if only to omit a reference (which will not stop the processing, but *will* leave an unresolved `\cite`),

After compiling again with LaTeX, if the change to the `.bib` file was correct, the job will finish, and the output will be what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

{ \end {thebibliography}
This if written as  \end {thebibliography} then it may run. Please check that curly brackets should be in pairs.